# Forwarding one single connection to multiple parallel

Tags: networking, video, proxy, streaming

I'd like to stream video data between two linux servers.

They are far from each other, and sender's uplink is ~20MBps (based on iperf3).

There is however some ISP limitation which I'd like to defeat:

1st test run:

```
server:~# iperf3 -s
client:~# iperf3 -c SERVERIP -R
... measuring...
[  4]   0.00-30.00  sec  21.8 MBytes  6.09 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

6.09MBits/sec is well below the ISPs ratings so I've tried making parallel connections with iperf for the 2nd test run:

```
server:~# iperf3 -s
client:~# iperf3 -c SERVERIP -R -P 8
... measuring...
[SUM]   0.00-30.00  sec  71.9 MBytes  20.1 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

That's nice, 20MBits/sec is close to the max bandwidth.

Streaming video with 20MBits/sec average bandwidth would pretty much result a good quality video, whereas trying the same with 6MBps will result far worse quality.

If the video player and streaming server is not capable of parallelling the stream, do I have any option, like reverse proxy, vpn, or anything which can tunnel one single connection into multiple, just like how `iperf -P 8` does?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm from first hand, that the combination of `multicat` with `aggregartp` and `reordertp` (from VideoLAN, makers of VLC) [to be found here](http://www.videolan.org/projects/multicat.html) will do what you need even for broadcast quality streams.

- Create multiple `aggregartp` / `reordertp` stream links for a single combined RTP stream
- Use `multicat` (or whatever you want) to feed your stream into `aggregartp`

That said, to keep things easy, you might want to reconsider: Tuning everything on the encoder side might make it possible to put a very good quality stream into 6Mbit/s (AFAIK the highest setting fro Netflix!) and just be done with it.